# Weird black space behind artboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop and opened new artboard and notice a strange black/grey area behind it. It stands out more when I try to save the file as it turns that area white.

What is causing it and how do I stop it?

Thanks

[image: Black/grey spacing behind artboard]

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Is it file specific, i.e.only affecting the design you are working on, or does it do it on a new blank document with new artboards?

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing your layers panel, but it looks like you might have a background layer outside of the artboards.